# display unique values between two dataframe columns - pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

say I have two "ID" columns in 2 dataframes, I want to display ID from DF1 that doesnt exists in DF2

I dont know if I should use join, merge, or isin.

```
cond = [df.name != df3.name]
df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
```

not sure if changing the condition will give me the result.

Answer (score 4):

In pyspark,you can use leftanti join,

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(0,'val1'),(1,'val2'),(4,'val4')],['id','val'])    
>>> df1.show()
+---+----+
| id| val|
+---+----+
|  0|val1|
|  1|val2|
|  4|val4|
+---+----+

>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(0,'val1'),(1,'val2'),(3,'val3'),(2,'val2')],['id','val'])
>>> df2.show()
+---+----+
| id| val|
+---+----+
|  0|val1|
|  1|val2|
|  3|val3|
|  2|val2|
+---+----+

>>> df1.join(df2,'id','leftanti').show()
+---+----+
| id| val|
+---+----+
|  4|val4|
+---+----+
```

Similarly,

```
>>> df2.join(df1,'id','leftanti').show()
+---+----+
| id| val|
+---+----+
|  3|val3|
|  2|val2|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

use `isin` and fir `~df1['id]` for dataframe compare.

df1:

```
 id name
    0   1    a
    1   2    b
    2   3    c
    3   4    d
```

df2:

```
id name
0   1   aa
1   5   bb
2   2   cc
3  10   dd

result = df1.loc[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])]

result

    id name
2   3    c
3   4    d
```

hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: there is an error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'. this is maybe for a pandas df?

Comment: can you please show me your code. do you create df1 and df2

Comment: `loc` was introduced in 0.11, so you'll need to upgrade your pandas .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet which uses isin from pyspark.sql to filter the ids that you are not interested. map/lambda function is used to build a list of ids to be filtered.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark_session = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("test_isin") \
        .getOrCreate()

    dict1 = [[1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c'], [4,'d']]
    dict2 = [[1, 'aa'], [5,'bb'], [2, 'cc'], [10, 'dd']]

    df1 = spark_session.createDataFrame(dict1, ["id", "name"])
    df2 = spark_session.createDataFrame(dict2, ["id", "name"])

    df2_id = df2.select(df2.id).collect()

    ids_to_be_filtered = []

    map(lambda each : ids_to_be_filtered.append(each.id), df2_id)

    result = df1[~df1.id.isin(df2_id)]

    result.show()
```

Also here's the link to documentation 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin

Please don't forget to let me know if it solved your problem :)